# Get my Action’s server URL in (JavaScript) fulfilment code

Tags: node.js, url, actions-on-google, fulfillment

I am using `actionssdk` and I build my Action fulfilments using Javascript and node.js + Express. 
I am looking for a way to get the url (protocol + host name + port) of the server where the fulfilment is hosted.

Is there a simple way to do this? E.g. in the `MAIN` intent? Is there some `conv`-property I can use? Can I get hold of a `req`-parameter in the `MAIN`-intent, from which I can deduct hostname etc?

```
const express = require('express');
const expressApp = express();
const { actionssdk, ... } = require('actions-on-google');

const app = actionssdk({
  ordersv3: true,
  clientId: ...
});

expressApp.post('/fulfilment', app);

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN',  (conv) => {
  let myUrl: string = ... // ???????
  ...
});
```

(*background*: obviously I know myself to where I deployed my fulfilment code. But I have a reusable template for fulfilment code in which I want to refer to the host url, and I do not want to type that in manually each time I develop a new Action).

Comment: I don't believe there's any way to get the server URL in the request, as that is assumed when it is called.

Comment: You can get the server url from a request `req` with `myUrl=req.protocol+"://"+req.headers.host`. But I do not know how to do that in my code above

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to the request object in a middleware via [Framework Metadata](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/c12e5da0c1585dec0b276a973393adc8ae291a0c/src/service/actionssdk/actionssdk.ts#L101) which is by default of type [BuiltinFrameworkMetadata](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/c12e5da0c1585dec0b276a973393adc8ae291a0c/src/framework/framework.ts#L49) which contains [objects used by Express](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs/blob/c12e5da0c1585dec0b276a973393adc8ae291a0c/src/framework/express.ts#L32)

For example, you can use it like this, which will be ran before each request:

```es6
app.middleware((conv, framework) => {
  console.log(framework.express.request.headers.host)
})
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for!